# How to remove a certain number from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

My code so far does everything it is supposed to do but one thing, it is supposed to exclude "0" from the array and I am not sure how to implement that into my code and exclude the number 0 when it counts positive (pozitivne) numbers in my code.

This is my code:

```
Integer[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87, 12};

    int pos2 = 0, neg2 = 0;

    for (int i : array) {
        if (i >= 0) {
            pos2++;
        } else {
            neg2++;
        }
    }

    p1 = new int[pos2];
    n1 = new int[neg2];

    pos2 = 0;
    neg2 = 0;

    for (int i : array) {
        if (i >= 0) {
            p1[pos2] = i;
            pos2++;
        } else {
            n1[neg2] = i;
            neg2++;
        }

    }

    System.out.print("Ukupno: ");
    for (int i : array) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }

    System.out.print("\nPozitivni: ");
    for (int i : p1) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }

    System.out.print("\nNegativni: ");
    for (int i : n1) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }}}
```

Comment: Did you try change your if condition to i > 0 instead of i >=0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two conditions here one for positives another for negatives. If you just remove "=" from  condition (i >= 0) then '0' will go into negative's array.

```
Integer[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87, 12};

int pos2 = 0, neg2 = 0;

for (int i : array) {
    if (i > 0) {
        pos2++;
    } else if(i < 0){
        neg2++;
    }
}

p1 = new int[pos2];
n1 = new int[neg2];

pos2 = 0;
neg2 = 0;

for (int i : array) {
    if (i > 0) {
        p1[pos2] = i;
        pos2++;
    } else if(i < 0){
        n1[neg2] = i;
        neg2++;
    }

}

System.out.print("Ukupno: ");
for (int i : array) {
    System.out.print(" " + i);
}

System.out.print("\nPozitivni: ");
for (int i : p1) {
    System.out.print(" " + i);
}

System.out.print("\nNegativni: ");
for (int i : n1) {
    System.out.print(" " + i);
}}}
```

Same result using collections, only one loop is required to filter positives and negatives.

```
    Integer[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87, 12};

     List<Integer> pos1 = new ArrayList<>();
     List<Integer> neg1 = new ArrayList<>();

     for (int i : array) {
         if (i > 0) {
             pos1.add(i);
         } else if(i < 0){
             neg1.add(i);
         }
     }

     System.out.print("Ukupno: ");
     for (int i : array) {
         System.out.print(" " + i);
     }

     System.out.print("\nPozitivni: ");
     for (int i : pos1) {
         System.out.print(" " + i);
     }

     System.out.print("\nNegativni: ");
     for (int i : neg1) {
         System.out.print(" " + i);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if (i >= 0) {` to `if (i > 0) {`

Also, change your `} else {` to `} else if (i < 0) {`

This is because you are including 0 with the `>=`. If you remove the `=`, it should be fine.